# Subclipse generates a nested working copy?

Tags: svn, subclipse

I am trying to integrate Subclipse 1.8.x into our existing Subversion 1.7.x work environment, which includes Tortoise.  When I use the **Team|Share Project...** feature to add a project to an existing working copy, Subclipse creates a new nested working copy at the requested location rather than adding the project to the existing working copy.  Tortoise reports this as a nested working copy.

I'm not sure if nested working copies should always be avoided, but they are definitely harder to use.  I can work around the issue by detaching the project in Eclipse, adding the project from Tortoise, committing the changes from Tortoise, and then reimporting the project in Eclipse.

Is there a way for Subclipse to automatically use an existing working copy when adding a new project?  Is the problem that the location of the project is several levels down from the top level of the working copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you share a project, one of two things happens:

1) Subclipse recognizes that the project is already a valid SVN working copy.  In which case it will just "connect" it to SVN so that you can use SVN actions on it.

2) It will turn the project into a working copy by offering to create a folder in the repository, check it out at the same location, and then let you add the rest of the files.

If you are creating projects inside a folder structure that happens to already be a working copy there is no way to detect this as SVN just reports the same status as if it were some random folder.  In this situation, I would suggest you use TortoiseSVN to add at least the project root folder to SVN so that it can be recognized as part of a working copy. Subclipse should then be able to connect it to SVN and handle the rest from there.

Comment: Great, that worked.  The added project root folder must be a committed change, not just added in the working copy.